# Tensor product of $R^2 \otimes_R S $

Tags: proof-verification, commutative-algebra, tensor-products

I have the following $R = k[[t^2,t^3]]$ and $S = k[[t^2,t^3]]/(t^2,t^3)$. I want to compute $R^2 \otimes_R S$. I think it would be something along the lines $$(k[[t^2,t^3]],k[[t^2,t^3]])\otimes_R k[[t^2,t^3]]/(t^2,t^3) = (k[[t^2,t^3]] \otimes_R  k[[t^2,t^3]]/(t^2,t^3),k[[t^2,t^3]] \otimes_R k[[t^2,t^3]]/(t^2,t^3)) = (k[[t^2,t^3]]/(t^2,t^3),k[[t^2,t^3]]/(t^2,t^3)).$$

Am I right? Also, the very last equality I am not sure how to justify, so if anyone has an idea, I would really appreciate it. Thanks so much!

Comment: Sorry, I missed that part. I just edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general if $R,S$ are commutative rings and $S$ is an $R$-algebra (i.e. there exists a ring homomorphism $R \rightarrow S$) then we have the following isomorphism of $R$-algebras (thus also a ring isomorphism):
$$R^2 \otimes_R S = (R\oplus R) \otimes_R S \cong(R\otimes_R S) \oplus (R \otimes_R S) = S \oplus S = S^2$$
Since $R\otimes_R S \cong S$ wich can be proven by giving mutually inverse homomorphisms in each direction.